# Importing a package that uses cgo

Tags: go, cgo

I am trying to build a project with a library that uses cgo to do some computation, my folder structure looks like this:

```
project/
├── main.go
├── library
   ├── lib.h
   ├── lib.c 
   ├── lib.go
   └── lib_test.go
```

When trying to run tests from inside the library package, everything works fine, but when i try to build an executable from inside my project and execute it, it fails with a `SIGSEG`.

I tried to debug the error with gdb, it looks like i am missing the cgo types definitions for some reason:

```
(r1=<optimized out>) at _cgo_gotypes.go:1018
1018    _cgo_gotypes.go: No such file or directory.
```

My `lib.go` have this as a header:

```
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -ldl
import "C"

func f() error {
  C.calling_into_c_code()
}
```

I am not very familiar with the working of cgo, any idea on how to resolve this?